# How should I improve this answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

First of all the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160851/in-html-how-can-i-obtain-user-input-and-display-it-on-the-main-page/

It is common for us to walk by this type of post and just downvote it, ignore it or flag it (or a combination of the 3).

I thought I would simply help the OP out in a nice, welcoming and friendly way for a new user.

There is almost no way to answer a question like this without links, and to cover most bases, a lot of links. This answer cannot be covered with code given the scope. It definitely was not a "link only" answer and had some context. So, how can I improve this answer?

If I can be honest it being deleted kinda ticks me off a little bit as it was made with good intentions to help the user. It makes me not want to offer friendly help to new users if I can be honest.

The first impression we set on this guy is 5 downvotes, an answer that probably helped him disappearing suddenly from the page and his question being closed.

Comment: *"If I can be honest it being deleted kinda ticks me off a little bit as it was made with good intentions to help the user. It makes me not want to offer friendly help to new users if I can be honest."* - you lose me there. How does the (low) quality of someone else's answer influence your own capability to help?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I had the only answer and the part that "ticks me off" was that it was deleted. Which the answer being deleted does not affect any capability to help, it affects my willingness to do so.

Comment: @jesse Ah, the fact that it was your answer is what I missed.

Comment: @will thanks for the advice bro. I'm starting to wonder now if I should keep on doing it and not care if they delete it eventually. This site is a about helping. people and it seems like a lot of people have forgotten that over the years. We are in the mind state of "killing a few people is ok" and that's how governments think. An individual deserves help if I think they do, and anyone who deletes the answer is contributing to the problem.

Comment: @Jesse yeah, killing people, that's equivalent.  The problem is, and has been all over the internet, is that if a help site is overwhelmed with terrirble questions (e.g., help-vamprie questions, easily answered by a minimal effort questions, nonsensical questions, spam, reposts upon myriad reposts), then the *experts who are willing to help answer questions* are driven away.  Without good volunteers to answer questions, the site degrades and becomes worthless. We sacrifice answering any old question in order to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @Jesse SO's minimum standards aren't crazy, or hard to meet. I see users with 1 rep who ask very good questions all the damn time--even non-native speakers!  It really isn't that hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is almost no way to answer a question like this without links, and to cover most bases, a lot of links. This answer cannot be covered with code given the scope. It definitely was not a "link only" answer and had some context. So, how can I improve this answer?

Short of importing all the content from the links and creating a monolith of an answer (and running the risk of violating some copyright policies), you can't.

On the answer being link-only: if you were to remove all the links and any of the text that depends on the links from your answer, here's what you would have left:

> Firstly, Welcome to StackOverflow.
>
> This can be accomplished in so many ways that this question is bound to be closed soon.
>
> This all depends on your project, what you want to do, and some of it is personal preference. So click around, google around, find your corner of the programming world and start tapping on your keyboard!
>
> Happy Programming!

... which doesn't seem worth splitting hairs over.

I understand you wanting to help, but there is only so much we can do. Some things are just way too broad to be sufficiently covered in one or even a handful of Stack Overflow questions. And that is why we eschew trying to answer these questions in favor of simply closing them.

Comment: So am I correct to assume that the answer should not have been nuked alongside the question?

Comment: @Jesse: Put it this way: the question is probably going to be nuked eventually. I wouldn't have deleted your answer specifically since you took the time to answer the question, but I wouldn't count on it surviving for very long.

Comment: It's not even really about the rep. Just about someone coming through and saying "What is this, this is not helpful to anyone, I will delete this" I already knew that the question would get nuked eventually. It produces a bad vibe. If the question is being nuked, why even mess with the answer in the first place. It seems illogical that the answer was even touched. Edit: To delete an obvious attempt at helping someone knowing the question would be closed, is going to disgruntle anyone, everytime, there is no other way to see it. Ya know?

Comment: @Jesse: Yeah, I know the feel. It seems counterproductive to delete an answer to a question when the problem lies in the question moreso the answer. The user hasn't taken any steps to improve their question either despite your efforts :(

Comment: Well dude. Yea man. Thanks for the empathy for sure. I'm 100% sure this site will survive without me, but I'm ready to ditch on principal alone. I don't have to help people on here after work every day and this type of thing really gets to me.

Comment: Im going to bed, thanks for your reponse

Comment: @Jesse: Yeah, Stack Overflow is absolutely not the best when it comes to helping individuals. But where it excels is content that applies to a wide audience through specific answers to focused questions. While you may find yourself spending tremendous amounts of effort to help one particular individual who may or may not even appreciate your time, my experience has been that it's much more satisfying to explain a concept in a way that will help dozens, maybe hundreds or even thousands of readers understand. I dare say it's how I got to where I am today (well, that and plenty of free time).

Comment: It's a little bit different on meta. Sure we get plenty of folks coming here with nothing but complaints and rants, but fairly often we get well-meaning folks such as yourself coming along. I took the time to respond to your post for this reason. We really want you to have a good experience here - I think you can start by redirecting your answering efforts to where it counts. Have a good rest.